# How can I open the screen using local notification?

Tags: ios, swift3

I searched alot about this problem but I did not get any relevant thing , is their any possibility to open screen by using local notification when our app is closed?

Comment: When user click notification do you want to open your app or certain view of the app?

Answer (score 0):

If the user taps the notification your app will launch and come to the front. Otherwise no.